# SQL Server: Why does adding a null to a variable not cause an error?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure that has a loop based on a counter.  When the counter becomes NULL the loop ends without any error.  Why doesn't SQL Server at least display a warning or error message like other programming languages?

Here is a code sample which exhibits the problem:

```
DECLARE @MasterCount int = 0;
DECLARE @Count int; -- initialized to NULL by SQL Server

PRINT 'Starting'

IF (@MasterCount IS NULL)
    PRINT '@MasterCount IS NULL';
ELSE 
    PRINT '@MasterCount ' + CAST(@MasterCount AS varchar(10))

IF (@Count IS NULL)
    PRINT '@Count IS NULL';

WHILE (@MasterCount IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    SET @MasterCount += @Count;

    IF @@ERROR <> 0 PRINT 'Error occured!'

    PRINT 'Loop @Count ' + CAST(@Count AS varchar(10))

    SET @Count -= 1;
END

IF @@ERROR <> 0 PRINT 'Error occured!'

IF (@MasterCount IS NULL)
    PRINT '@MasterCount IS NULL';
ELSE 
    PRINT '@MasterCount ' + CAST(@MasterCount AS varchar(10))

PRINT 'Ending'
```

Produces the following output:

```
Starting
@MasterCount 0
@Count IS NULL

@MasterCount IS NULL
Ending
```

Comment: why are you expecting an error?

Comment: I was expecting similar behavior to other programming languages where adding NULL to a numeric value is an error.  It's odd to me that this is not the case with SQL Server.

Comment: `NULL + something` equals `NULL`. I don't see the problem, really, "undefined + 1" is "indefined"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't raise an error because this is defined, documented behaviour.

If you have two apples and you know the weight of only one then it makes sense that the weight of both of them added together is not known.

You can actually get a warning to appear if you slightly alter the formulation.
Instead of

```
SET @MasterCount += @Count;
```

You could use

```
SELECT @MasterCount = SUM(C)
FROM   (VALUES(@Count),
              (@MasterCount )) V(C);
```

In which case it gives

> Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET
>   operation.

This does change the semantics however. As the null value was entirely ignored you would end up with `@MasterCount` simply being assigned back its original value rather than being set to `null` in your scenario.